# MySQL regexp json

Tags: mysql, regex

can you help me with regular expression in Mysql?

i have these rows in a table

```
{"id":"1","value":"2"},{"id":"2","value":["5"]}
{"id":"1","value":"2"},{"id":"2","value":["1","5","14"]}
{"id":"1","value":"2"},{"id":"2","value":["3","2","12"]}
{"id":"1","value":"2"},{"id":"2","value":["3","1"]}
```

and I want SELECT -> all rows with id:2 and value 5 (first 2 rows).

```
WHERE `extra_fields` REGEXP '"id":"2","value":\\["5"\\]' ;
```

I tried this REGEXP but it is not correctly working. My REGEXP SELECT only first row.

Comment: If you're going to use a relational database, then put your data in tables.

Comment: is this json stored as data in a column in mysql?

Comment: Why are you storing JSON in your database?  That is a horrible idea.  As can see, searching inside it is going to be a nightmare.

Comment: @RocketHazmat storing JSON in a database is not a bad idea if you're not going to search within the JSON.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Fair enough.

Comment: I would *HIGHLY* consider re-thinking your database structure if you are going to be searching.  Sounds like you want a link table to link together ids to multiple values.

Comment: @RocketHazmat made the suggestion into an answer

Comment: @RocketHazmat what about when you need a table that takes an arbitrary number of rows of a like object. you will need to use json, as JOINING will not work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
WHERE `extra_fields` REGEXP '"id":"2","value":\\[("[[:digit:]]*",)?"5"' ;
```

Comment: Assuming there are no other keys between `id` and `value`, assuming they are always in that order.  Also, this will only work if `5` is the last value.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: right, it is corrected

Comment: this REGEXP return null rows :(

Comment: @TomášTrúsik: try this new edit

Comment: @TomášTrúsik - Take your JSON data, write some code in a language of your choice that has a JSON parser, and convert the JSON objects to one or more CSV files. Then import the CSV file(s) into one or more tables.

Comment: @Cisimir et Hippolyte: works perfectly :) very big thx

Comment: it`s possible this query works fine but when I use this query in PHP script result is bad. can it be that i add \ before '?

`code`            $query = mysql_query('
            SELECT 
                *
            FROM 
                `'.$obj->dbprefix.'k2_items` 
            WHERE 
                `extra_fields` REGEXP \'"id":"2","value":\\[("[[:digit:]]*",)?"5"\'  AND
                `published` = 1 
            '); `code`

Answer (score 1):

You should rethink your database schema:

Assuming your current table is named `main` and has a primary key named `id` and its type is `INT(10)` and it's set to auto-increment

```
main
  id           INT(10) PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
  extra_fields TEXT    NOT NULL  -- bad
```

: `extra fields` looks like a collection of fields. Each field has an ID and a collection of values:

```
fields
  id      INT(10) PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
  type_id INT(10) NOT NULL
  main_id INT(10) NOT NULL
  values  TEXT    NOT NULL -- still bad
```

but we want to search inside the values, so let's normalize it further (which is always a good idea), and make a new table `FIELD_VALUES`. Since now the `FIELDS` table is now nothing but a collection of all pairs of `id`,`main_id`, we don't need this table, and we're left with:

```
main
  id   INT(10) PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
  ...

field_values
  id      INT(10) PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT 
  type_id INT(10) NOT NULL
  main_id INT(10) NOT NULL
  value   TEXT    NOT NULL
```

with contents like

```
main_id type_id value
    1       1     2
    1       2     5
    2       1     2
    2       2     1
    2       2     5
    2       2     14
    ...
```

Then you can easily query this table:

```
WHERE id IN(
  SELECT main_id
  FROM   field_values
  WHERE  type_id = 2
  AND    value   = 5
)
```

If your extra fields can take different shape and you still want them searchable, you'll need to reflect their shape with extra tables.

If you can't capture the entire shape of the JSON (or, almost JSON - the outer pair of square brackets is missing) but you still want it to be searchable, you can make an index table(s) (just like `field_values`) and still keep the original JSON in the main table. Then it suffices when the index table(s) reflects enough of the JSON structure to be searchable.